# DropDownList is not storing values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an e-commerce app and the problem is in showing the quantity of items purchased. The DropDownList shows the option to change quantity, it is in a gridview and it has a selectedindexchanged event. The event code works fine but when there are two(or more) products and we change the quantity of one row and then change the other rows's quantity, the previous row quantity is set back to default that is "1" while total price column shows the multiplication of price and quanity that we set to the DropDownList.

My DropDownList code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQty" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlQty_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

My C# code for the SelectedIndexChanged and GridView RowDataBoundevent:

```
protected void ddlQty_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlQty =(DropDownList)sender;
        int rowindex = int.Parse(ddlQty.Attributes["rowindex"].ToString());
        ViewState["index"] = rowindex;
        ViewState["I"] = ddlQty.SelectedValue;

        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex]["Price"].ToString());
        decimal totalprice = price * Convert.ToInt32(ddlQty.SelectedValue);
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex]["TotalPrice"] = totalprice;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalPrice"] = decimal.Parse(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalPrice"].ToString()) + totalprice - Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex]["Price"].ToString());
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = "Total Amount =";
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalPrice"].ToString();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlQty");
            ddl.Attributes.Add("rowindex", e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());
            if (ViewState["index"] != null)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() == ViewState["index"].ToString())
                {
                    ddl.SelectedValue = ViewState["I"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am attaching an image also to make it more clear.

[image]

Comment: How are you binding ddlQty? I'm guessing on Page_Load and not checking for IsPostback.

Comment: No, the binding function is called only when `!IsPostBack`

Comment: debug and check for the first row in `GridView1_RowDataBound` what `ViewState["I"]` is holding

Comment: Just an idea but. when doing this: `DropDownList ddlQty =(DropDownList)sender;` aren't you setting the DropDownList ddlQty to reset(be) so it won't have selected the Item that was selected? I think my idea is a bullshit sry :D but I just think there might be some problem around that DropDownList declaration..

Comment: @Dotnet: It is not passing the if condition `ViewState["index"] != null` and thus storing nothing in `ViewState["I"]`

Comment: You are updating the price when the quantity changes: `ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex]["TotalPrice"] = totalprice;`. Why are you not storing/updating also the quantity in the datatable?

Comment: It sounds like your RowDataBound event is firing before the SelectedIndexChanged event.  You may have to reorganize your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think your grid is binding on each postback made by dropdownlist, so changing one value will overwrite the formerly stored value in VS. You should try storing these values as a list, appending changes to it instead of replacing it each time.

IMHO, anyway, I would go by setting AutoPostBack properties to false, and updating row calculations client-side, then validating on server side on submit.